# Spinning curve vertices

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create a circular saw blade like the one pictured here, which I grabbed off blendswap.

[image]

I thought I might be able to create the handles for one of the teeth, then spin around the origin for the rest - there is no spin tool for curves though.

Is there a way to create this saw blade, without scripting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Model a single tooth.
   [image: tooth]
2. Add an *Array* modifier, and a *Curve* modifier to that tooth object.
3. Add a new circle curve <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Curve > Circle
4. Set the *Fit Type* of the array modifier to *Fit Curve*, and target the Bezier Circle (added in step 3). Also set the *Object* of the curve modifier to the Bezier Circle.
   [image: modifiers]

If the teeth overlap, you can scale the circle to get the teeth to line up perfectly.

[image: saw blade]

Comment: +1 from me. Your technique is much better than mine. The advantage is you can easily and precisely adjust the radius of the wheel and the size of the teeth.

Comment: Is it possible to make this a solid disk (with a hole in the middle) without applying the modifiers?

Answer (score 7):

Add a ***Bezier Circle*** (*Add-->Curve-->Circle*) and delete one of its vertex.
[image]

Select the whole curve and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open it up.
[image]

Shape the curve to make it look as a grinding wheel tooth. Use <kbd>V</kbd> button to change the *handle type*, so you may for example make the teeth sharper.
[image]

Add an ***Empty***, then set the ***Array Modifier*** for a curve (with the settings pictured below). Set the *Count* amount as desired. Rotate an *Empty* to create a grinding wheel. Now changing the shape of a one tooth will affect every other one. 
[image]

In Object Mode press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to convert your curve to a mesh.
[image]

If you need more teeth, increase the *Count* amount and scale the curve to make the teeth fit each other. Enable a *First Last* checkbox to merge the first and the last teeth.
[image]